# How to avoid a whole Text component move to the next line in flexWrap: 'wrap'

Tags: react-native

Let's take an example. I have two Text components as below:

```
<View style={{flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
   <Text>12345</Text>
   <Text>67890</Text>
</View>
```

**My expected result is :** (The second text component will be splitted out and moved to the next line)

```
12345678
90
```

**The actual result is :** (The whole second text component will be move to the next line when the line do not have enough width for putting the whole text component.)

```
12345
67890
```

For this purpose, how can i change the code? Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

React native supports nested Text Componentss, basically meaning you can reference different strings in order to get the result in which you've desired. Im not tooo sure why you are doing this though :P Some sample code is below. Note that using flexWrap is not required.

```
<View style = {{width: 50, backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0'}}>
      <Text>1234578
          <Text>9123456</Text>
      </Text>
</View>
```

With the output of below...

[image]

Hope this helps!

EDIT #1: Another possible solution?

```
<View style = {{width: 50, backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0'}}>
      <Text>
           {123456789}
           {412346789}
      </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Hello Ryan, thanks for the advice. it is a great solution but not suit for me. Actually i am trying to convert dynamic html to native component. And i need to make some child view for some complex components. But i knew that we cant have a nested view child component for the text component.